# Web assembly performance of rem instruction

Tags: javascript, performance, webassembly

During some experiments with wasm, I found that my hand coded wasm take 2 times more than it's js
alternative, and it is related to `i32.rem_s` operation.

## wat code:

```
(module
  (func $add (param $p1 i32)
    (result i32)
    (local $i i32) (local $s i32)
    (local.set $i (local.get $p1))
    (local.set $s (i32.const 0))
    loop $while
      (i32.add (local.get $i) (local.get $s))
      (i32.rem_s (i32.const 1000007))
      local.set $s
      (i32.add (local.get $i) (i32.const -1))
      local.set $i
      (i32.ne (i32.const 0) (local.get $i)) 
      br_if $while
    end
    local.get $s
  )
  (export "add" (func $add))
)
```

## js code (including the benchmark code):

```
import { add } from "./add.wasm";

const n = 100000000;
const x = new Date;
console.log(add(n));
console.log(new Date - x);

const y = new Date;
let s = 0;
for (let i = n; i > 0; i -= 1) {
  s = (s + i) % 1000007;
}
console.log(s);
console.log(new Date - y);
```

## result:

```
244650
892
244650
483
```

Where is the problem? My hand coded assembly is not optimized? JS has a very
intelligent optimization? Or it is a bug in V8's wasm runner?

I'm running this on my Ubuntu with intel corei7, using nodejs v14.2.0 if it is important.

Comment: It's true. On latest Chrome 81.0.4044.138 I got:
add (wasm): 643ms
add (js): 325ms

On FF 76:

add (wasm): 258ms
add (js): 262ms

See my micro benchmark with warmups:
https://webassembly.studio/?f=b1zvyell1p

Answer (score 0):

You have performed what I would term a ‘micro benchmark’, a very small piece of code that uses a limited number of instructions that is iterated many times. This technique for benchmarking is wildly inaccurate!

Yes, JavaScript, once optimised can meet near native performance.

You are comparing quite different operations - JavaScript numbers are all floating point under the hood, whereas with WebAssembly you are using 32bit integers.

Comment: I don't want to say that wasm is bad and always is 2x slower than js, but I expect that wasm could perform the same optimizations that js has, and js with floating point is solving a harder problem and should take more time than wasm. ( if not, why? )